# Using (A)GPL library in Apache License 2 licensed application

Tags: apache-2.0, agpl

I have developed a modular text extraction framework (https://github.com/dankito/TextExtraction) that I like to put under the permissive Apache License 2.

One of the separate modules is using latest iText version which is licensed under AGPL license.

Therefore I have put that module under AGPL.

My question is now, do I also have to put the UI module under AGPL

- if it links the AGPL module statically (like with Maven or Gradle)?
- If it links the AGPL module dynamically? (You can add it as plug-in at runtime, no compile time dependencies to it.)